# Why memory in /proc/cgroup is different from the total I calculate from file system?

Tags: linux, kernel, cgroups

There are two methods to get the total of memory cgroup, calculate it from file system like `find /sys/fs/cgroup/memory -type d | wc -l` or `cat /proc/cgroups`. But I find that the two methods get different results. Here is the command output:

```bsh
root@root-ubuntu:~$ find /sys/fs/cgroup/memory -type d | wc -l
62
root@root-ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/cgroups 
#subsys_name hierarchy num_cgroups enabled
cpuset 8 1 1
cpu 2 1 1
cpuacct 2 1 1
blkio 7 1 1
memory 10 109 1
devices 12 60 1
freezer 11 2 1
net_cls 3 1 1
perf_event 9 1 1
net_prio 3 1 1
hugetlb 4 1 1
pids 6 62 1
rdma 5 1 1
```

OS info:

```bsh
root@root-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux root-ubuntu 5.8.0-44-generic #50~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 10 21:07:30 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```